# Defining a new variable from division of another two variables with bash script

Tags: bash, shell, arithmetic-expressions

I have 2 variables which are up_votes and down_votes from a csv dataset. I am trying to create a new variable as percentage of up_votes / total_votes. For example, up_votes=296 down_votes=255, my output should be 53.7 but I get 25600.
Here is my equations.

```
    x=$col3
    y=$col3+$col4
    z=($x/$y)*100
    ans=$z
```

Comment: The code you posted isn't sufficient to reproduce your problem : https://ideone.com/fq6BYp ; that said 25600 is 256 * 100 and 256 is the exit code you'd get for an invalid command, for instance `($x/$y)`. Anyway bash doesn't handle float arithmetics so you'll have to use an external command such as `dc`

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40786/how-to-do-integer-float-calculations-in-bash-or-other-languages-frameworks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use external programs to do calculations because bash does not support float point arithmetic

```sh
#!/bin/bash


votes="topic1,0,0 topic2,296,255 topic3,3,4"

for vote_data in $votes ; do
    topic=`echo $vote_data|sed -r 's/([^,]*),([^,]*),(.*)/\1/'`
    up_votes=`echo $vote_data|sed -r 's/([^,]*),([^,]*),(.*)/\2/'`
    down_votes=`echo $vote_data|sed -r 's/([^,]*),([^,]*),(.*)/\3/'`

#    echo "$topic , up: $up_votes, down: $down_votes"

    total=`awk "BEGIN {print ($up_votes+$down_votes)}"`
    if [ $total -eq 0 ];then
    ans=divbyzero
    else
    ans=`awk "BEGIN {print 100.0*$up_votes/( $up_votes+$down_votes)}"`
    fi
    echo "$topic $ans [ $up_votes / $down_votes ]"

done
```

**output:**

```
topic1 divbyzero [ 0 / 0 ]
topic2 53.7205 [ 296 / 255 ]
topic3 42.8571 [ 3 / 4 ]
```

Comment: Actually, I get this votes from csv file so votes are not constant like in your example. When I try with variables it gives awk: division by zero error. I am trying to insert this dataset into postgresql table by the way. https://ideone.com/iNCGYo

Comment: so check for the cases when there are no votes at all and skip such case

Comment: I checked the first 100 rows and there are no null votes but Error returns in first row. Are you sure about the awk syntax?

Comment: I updated my answer to check for zeros just in case and to simulate your scenario. you can  copy paste my code and run it to check that it works.

Comment: Yeah, I checked now, and it works for me, too. Thanks.